# AppHarbor build error when setting expiration header on Amazon S3 put request (request.AddHeader)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-s3, appharbor

Added .NET Amazon SDK to my project, and was able to upload images to Amazon S3 with no problems, both on my local server and [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/).

Then I added this line to set the expiration header on upload to S3:

```
request.AddHeader("Expires", DateTime.Now.AddYears(10).ToString("r"));
```

This works just fine from my local server, correctly setting the Expires header on S3.

But when I push this code to AppHarbor, I get the following build error:

```
error CS1061: 'Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest' does not contain a definition for 
'AddHeader' and no extension method 'AddHeader' accepting a first argument of type 
'Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or 
an assembly reference?)
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should try downloading the [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) build output and run in a local IIS to verify that references work and are to correct AWS SDK versions.

Comment: Seems to run just fine in my local IIS. Anything special I should be checking for?

Comment: It has got to be because your code runs with a different version of the AWS SDK in your local machine than on AppHarbor. My guess is that you've gac'ed the 1.4 version on your local machine, but you're pushing a dll with version < 1.4 to AppHarbor. I can confirm that the AddHeader() doesn't exist in v1.2 (there's only AddHeaders()).

Comment: Yup - the AWS .dll that comes back down from AppHarbor is 1.0.14. No idea how that gets up to AppHarbor - that version doesn't exist anywhere on my local machine (just downloaded the v. 1.4 SDK to my machine for the first time two weeks ago). I'll figure that out and get back. Thanks MF!

Comment: Still can't figure out exactly what's going on - but falling back to addHeaders() certainly works for now.